# way to design a SQL schema where entities have fixed number of relationships but Number of Relationships depend on attributes

Tags: sql, schema, relational

In our schema we have a level entity and a pod entity. The pods are stored within the levels on ports. Ports are an attribute of levels. There are a varying amount of ports per level. We can Identify the number of ports based on a SKU for the level. How do we design a schema to account for a varying amount of ports per level in order to check that there is a port available for a new pod or not and to identify the ports for the largest levels vs the smallest.

Example:

level 1000 has 4 ports and three are filled.
level 4000 has 12 ports and none are available.

```
level table
-----------
level id
port_id1
port_id2
port_id3
port_id(n)


pod table
---------
pod_id
other attributes
```

Designing it in the form above would lead to nullable columns and we are not sure if that is the best practice given our setup.

Relational Schema:
[image: Relational Schema]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When an attribute of an entity varies in size ( in this case has between 4 and 12 ports) how do we account for all the ports of each level in the levels table and then check to see if the port is open before allowing a pod to be associated with that port on that level? Sorry I can try to clarify better if needed.

Comment: You probably have a very good idea in your head of what your schema and data look like; however, it is not very clear at all in your question. Can you update your post with some same data and any information on how the tables relate (if at all)?

Comment: Sorry it is hard to describe. I added my preliminary schema at the bottom link "Relational Schema". Port_Id(n) references any more ports depending on the level size. The best description I can come up with is the entity levels has different sized levels. we know the size based on the SKU of the level. size varies in the number of ports available. Our entity "Pods" are inserted in a port on a level. What is the best way of tracking the different sizes of the levels and the open ports available on them?

Comment: That helps some. Do you have a `Port` table which the `Port_IDn` fields relate?

Comment: Not currently. We were thinking that having a separate 'Ports' table would cause more abstraction and make our code more complicated. The 'Port_Id(n)' just stands for port 5-12 that I wrote down In a hurry to give better reference to the problem. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your schema and intent correctly, this is how I would approach it. *(Sorry I don't have pretty ERD software at work.)*

Simply, you are creating a normalized table to store the Level-to-Port relationships so that it can handle zero-to-many. You will likely want to add constraints to ensure uniqueness, etc; but this should be the general idea:

[image]

Based on your most recent clarifying comment, you could avoid using a `Port` table and replace the `Port_Id` field on `Levels_Port` with a `INT` field that stores your 5-12 value.

Comment: This is perfect! So you would definitely suggest either making the ports an entity or make it an attribute of the relationship between the pods and the levels?

Comment: If the ports are simply numbers, don't make a table for them, but do make sure you add a check constraint on the port number field so that you can make sure only valid port numbers are being used.

Comment: Sounds simple enough! Thanks again for the direction!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck!